# displaying images and playing sound in C#

Tags: c#, image, audio

I am learning C# and I want to create a countdown timer application that displays the time in a digital format on an image of a stopwatch and gives verbal time updates at certain times.
How do I go about displaying images to the screen and playing sound? I have used pygame in python to achieve this so basically I am looking for suggestions for something similar in C#.
I hope this makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best technology to use for that would probably be Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

Here's an example of an application made in WPF similar to what you want to do:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20048/Immerse-Yourself-in-WPF-A-quot-World-Clocks-quot-A